# Loading JSON config for paths using express and node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

So I have what is probably a noob question about routing in express and **node.js**

I have a middleware that loads a `JSON file` that contains all of the paths and configuration for these paths. The configuration file looks something like this

```
module.exports = {
"/account" :{
    template: "dashboard/account",
    page_title: "My Account",
    // more path configs....
},
"/account/:id/users" : {
    template: "dashboard/account/account-users",
    page_title: "Account Users",
    // more path configs....
}
}
```

And the middleware method that gets called in my app server when the app is created

```
app.use(middleware.getRouteConfig);
```

looks like this

```
var routeConfig = require('../config/route-config'); // path to the JSON above
getRouteConfig: function (req, res, next) {
    req.config = routeConfig[req.path];
    next();
},
```

And finally my express route looks like this

```
app.get('/account/:id/users',  function(req, res){
  // Get the users
  // 
});
```

Now lets say I go to /account/12345/users

Express noticed that the route has the `:id` in the middle and goes to that route. However my middleware then will try to load the `config` for that route and it can't find **/account/12345/users** in my JSON config file.

So my question is how do I load that route configuration using my **dynamic :id path variable** and get the configuration from the JSON file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Implement json parser using GSON SDK of Google.

You will found sample code from : http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

For json string validator  : http://jsonlint.com/